# Why would a service provider not be mocked?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I'm using a library to send send requests to Indeed jobs https://github.com/jobapis/jobs-indeed.

I have setup a provider so I can easily mock the requests and also so I don't have to setup my credentials every time I use it.

This library has 2 classes. A Query and Provider class. The Provider class is responsible for making the http request.

I can mock the Query class but I can't mock the Provider class.

Provider:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use JobApis\Jobs\Client\Queries\IndeedQuery;
use JobApis\Jobs\Client\Providers\IndeedProvider;

class JobSearchServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        // Register Indeeds API
        $this->app->bind(IndeedQuery::class, function() {
            // Build the required fields for indeeds api
            $indeed = new IndeedQuery([
                'publisher' => config('services.indeed.publisher'),
                'format' => 'json',
                'v' => '2',
            ]);

            return $indeed;
        });

        $this->app->bind(IndeedProvider::class, function() {
            // Use an empty query object so that we can initialise the provider and add the query in the controller.
            $queryInstance = app('JobApis\Jobs\Client\Queries\IndeedQuery');

            return new IndeedProvider($queryInstance);
        });
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public function searchIndeed(Request $request, IndeedQuery $query, IndeedProvider $client)
{
    dump($query);  // Returns a mockery object
    dd($client);   // Returns original object
}
```

Test:

```
public function testSearchIndeed()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $this->mock(IndeedQuery::class);
    $this->mock(IndeedProvider::class);

    $this->actingAs($user)
        ->get('indeed')
        ->assertStatus(200);
}
```

Why is the IndeedQuery being mocked but not the IndeedProvider?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.

Mockery doesn't throw errors if you try and mock a class that doesn't exist. I had a spelling mistake in my tests when requiring the class.

Controller

```
use JobApis\Jobs\Client\Providers\IndeedProvider;
```

Test

```
use JobApis\Jobs\Client\Provider\IndeedProvider; // Notice missing 's'
```

When using mockery you won't get errors if the class doesn't exist. So if the mockery object isn't being resolved check the spelling.